# Фиксация изменения ориентации View в iOS 6.0

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Как известно метод -shouldAutoroateToInterfaceOrientation депрекейчен с iOS 6.0. Моя задача ограничить возможность вращения некоторых View до только портретного режима. Каким образом этого можно достичь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/155969/) статья была вчера на эту тему